# limitations for multiple requests in asp.net 4.8 + IIS 10

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have an asp.net 4.8 web api hosted in IIS 10.

I have a controller with an uploadFile method.

when calling this endpoint from the front-end app:

- for calling it once for one file - all is ok.
- for calling it 5 times in a loop (each file needs to be uploaded separately) - all is ok
- for calling it 15 times in a loop - I get error 500 in some of the calls, and the others are successful.
  when trying to debug the problem, I see that if I call the "uploadFile" endpoint 15 times from the app, In the server side, this endpoint is triggered 9-10 times.
  I mean that some calls are returning error 500 but the call doesn't trigger the endpoint on the server side.

I'm not an expert in web api, so any help where to look will be appreciated.

EDIT: this is my post method in my ApiController:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<Models.Uploads.UploadFileResponse> UploadFile()
    {
        // log the entry
        Utils.LogHelper.WriteToLogFile("Entered UploadFile method in file contorller");

        // perform upload file operation
        return await _repository.UploadFileAsync(HttpContext.Current.Request).ConfigureAwait(false); ;
    }
```

In this method, I first log the entry, and then call the uploadFile method that performs all the operations.

My problem is that the endpoint is triggered 10-11 times (according to the log entries), but the app calls it 15 times.

Comment: Can you post action method code? Also since error is http 500 that means some kind of exception is happening in action method. Are you logging those exceptions somewhere? If yes then post them as well. Without these details its hard to know what going in your api.

Comment: @PankajKapare
I've updated the question with my action method. thanks.